# Return in Recursion and basic flow

Tags: c++, recursion, return

I am not able to understand the flow of program in recursion with and without return both.How do i return or print the group of values calculated by the function?For eg To calculate all the peak elements in an array I used recursion but I am not able to get how to give those values as a result.Basically I am not clear what happens if i write or not write return before the recursive function.

```
int  peak(int arr[],int i,int size)
{
    while(i<size)    
    {
        if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]&&arr[i]>arr[i-1])
            cout<<arr[i];
        i++;
        return peak(arr,i,size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Moreover this function is not returning the last peak value

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't make much sense. You use both loops *and* iteration?

Comment: Furthermore, you *will* go out of bounds of your array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude probably you mean *recursion*

Comment: @NiVeR Ah yes I do

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 2 ways to solve your problem.

First example uses loops for calculating sum of peaks:

```
int peak_sum(int arr[], int size)
{
    int sum = 0;

    // check first element
    if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
        std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;
        sum += arr[0];
    }

    // for each middle value in array
    for (int i = 1; i < size - 2; i++) {
        // if current value is peak
        if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1] && arr[i] > arr[i - 1]) {
            std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
            // then we add it to total sum of peaks
            sum += arr[i];
        }
    }

    // check last element
    if (arr[size - 1] > arr[size - 2]) {
        std::cout << arr[size - 1] << std::endl;
        sum += arr[size - 1];
    }    

    // after all we return this sum of peaks
    return sum;
}
```

But if you want to solve it in a recursive way then it may looks like this:

```
int
peak_sum(int arr[], int size, int index, int sum)
{
    // if index in bounds
    if (index < size) {
        // if we on the first element
        if (index == 0) {
            // if first element more then next: it is peak
            if (arr[index] > arr[index + 1]) {
                std::cout << arr[index] << std::endl;
                sum += arr[index];
            }

            // if we on the last element
        } else if (index == size - 1) {
            // if first element more then previous: it is peak
            if (arr[index] > arr[index - 1]) {
                std::cout << arr[index] << std::endl;
                sum += arr[index];
            }

            // else we in the middle
        } else {
            // if current element more then previous and next: it is peak
            if (arr[index] > arr[index - 1] && arr[index] > arr[index + 1]) {
                std::cout << arr[index] << std::endl;
                sum += arr[index];
            }
        }

        // anyway we check next value of array
        // by incrimeting current index
        return peak_sum(arr, size, index + 1, sum);
    } else {
        // otherwise we end iterating array
        return sum;
    }
}
```

And call it with:

```
//       array, size of it, initial index, initial sum
peak_sum(arr, array_size, 0, 0);
```

If you interested in flow of your code:

```
//example for array_size == 3

if (index in bounds) {
    index++;
    if (index in bounds) {
        index++;
        if (index in bounds) {
            index++;
            if (index in bounds) {}
            else return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see this too: https://www.ideone.com/jbDPwV. However, I found your answer gives more options +1.

Comment: In the iterative way this would not consider the peak element at the extremes that is at array index 0 and size-1.For eg in array 40 10 20 5 8;it would print only 20 but not 40 and 8.

Comment: I executed the recursive function .It is not printing individual peak elements.I want that to be printed .It is printing 0 which should not be the case as the sum is not zero.

Comment: @ANIKSHA, I just updated my code, check it now. Also, if array will have size less then three elements it may cause some bugs or errors. So it can be improved by adding special check for length in the beginning of each function.